# Appropriate data structure for returning all subsets of a set

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

I understand the algorithm for doing this but I don't know what data structure (array, linked list, vector, other?) would be best for returning the final set of sets since every example I see just asks to print the sets.

1. Can someone explain the thought process for deciding between the 3 data structures I mentioned?
2. Also, are vectors even used anymore? I heard they were obsolete but still see many recent examples.

To be clear, I mean **ALL** subsets, so they have different sizes.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the set of subsets? That will dictate which data structure to use.

Comment: Where you want use this subsets?

Comment: Where did you hear that vectors are obsolete? `std::vector` is probably the container most often used in C++.

Comment: To be clear, the number of subsets is 2^N, right? Do you *really* want to store 2^N distinct sets?

Comment: Rob has a good point. You should consider generating each subset as needed. Why store that potentially huge amount of data when you can generate it on demand? This reminds me of the procedural world generation used in the game Minecraft.

Comment: Rob: Yeah- maybe the question is a little unrealistic but I still would like to know what a good data structure for holding something of that structure would be.

Answer (score 2):

The decision of which data structure to use depends on:

- Type of data to be stored
- Operations that you intend to perform on the data

A normal array, would give you contiguous block of memory and random access to the elements, however you need to know the exact number of elements before hand so that you can allocate an array of appropriate size.

With `std::vector` you get random access to the data, and contiguous just like arrays but vector is a dynamic array,it grows as you add new elements, and a amortized constant complexity, however insertion/deletion of elements is faster only at the ends since all elements need to be moved.

With `std::list` you don't get the random access but insertion and deletion of elements is faster because it involves just moving around of the pointer links.

**Also, are vectors even used anymore?**
That is not true at all.
They are very much in use and one of the most widely used data structures provided by the Standard Library.

Comment: And this downvote is for? Atleast leave a comment of what you think is incorrect that deserves a downvote, If you cannot and just downvoted for no apparent technical reason, Please consider yourself not qualified enough for downvoting in future.Thank You.

Comment: Not the one to downvote, but actually `std::list` is a lot slower than `std::vector` even for random insertion. The biggest cost of using `std::list` is actually traversing it linearly to get to the point of insertion/deletion. In fact, since each traversal is a pointer dereference, you are jumping about randomly in memory, and ruining cache locality. The cost of shifting subsequent elements in memory for a `std::vector` is actually a lot smaller than traversing a linked list. Benchmarks done by Bjarne Stroustrup, and mentioned at the GoingNative2012 conference http://bit.ly/yHE7JZ

Answer (score 1):

Once i used bit fields to determine the subsets. Where if the `i` th bit is `1` then the `i` the element in the set is selected in the subset and `0` otherwise. In this case you need to store the ordering of the elements. The same can be done with `bool` vectors i think.

Comment: Interesting approach. It would be space-inefficient for the sparse subsets, but space-efficient for the dense subsets. I wonder how space-efficient it is overall.

Comment: I agree that the space requirement is higher for sparse subsets. How about doing RLE to the bitmap, and buy some space for time ?

Comment: If you're gonna trade time for space, you might as well generate the subsets on the fly. And the much smaller space might result in more speed because of the cache.